# How many batteries are required for a 3.5 kVA inverter?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I am planning to buy a 3.5 kVA small industrial inverter, but I am not able to figure out how many batteries are needed for that. Please anyone help me out with details.

Comment: Help us out with details first. What type of batteries (Voltage, Ampere-Hours) will you be using, and for how long will you be running the inverter, and with what load?

Comment: Run time at least - 8-10 Hours
Usage - 10 Computers, 1 fan, 5 Servers, 2 CFL

Comment: "10 Computers, 1 fan, 5 Servers, 2 CFL" that is some info, but what we realy need is the total power (Watt) required.

Comment: To give you a first-order estimate: assuming 2 kW for 10 hours (20kWH) and using 50AH 12V batteries (600WH each) you would need 34 batteries.

Comment: You should put extra information in the question - not (only) in comments.  Battery Vmean x Ah needed = Power x 1/(DOD_allowed_fraction) x time. eg 24V supply,  60% allowed DOD, 2 kVA mean load, 10 hours . VAbattery =2000W x 1/60% x 10h =  33,000 VAh. At 24V mean = 1375 Ah. Using 100 Ah Deep discharge batteries = 14 x 24V 100 Ah or 28 x 12V . Higher than Wouters figure due to 60% allowed DOD.  And I mean = 2000W / 24 = 83 A. Per battery in 14P2S or 28P1S = 6A/battery. = 16h rate (as you'd expect as 10h/60%~ = 17.  A few more would be safe. Say 30-40 x 100Ah 12V. (!)...

Comment: ... ie about the same number as  Wouter **BUT**  2 x capacity/battery. 100 Ah deep discharge batteries are an industry standard. | If in USA buy Trojan DD . If elsewhere look carefully. 60% is too deep if you discharge this often. 80% say may be OK if you do full discharge only seldom. Get them back to full charge ASASAP regardless.

Comment: Question is basically OK but needs beating into shape. Add details from comments and better describe what you are trying to achieve. Your load spec is too loose. What Vin? Why? What inverter? What application? Why not use an alternator as well. Why ...? What ...? Fail to tidy it up and the closing brigade will come knocking.

Answer (score 2):

> I am planing to bye a 3.5 KVA small industrial Inverter, but i am not able to figure out how many batteries needed for that. Please any one help me out with details.

Your question is missing critical pieces of information.

- Your required run-time.
- Your system voltage.

Energy in batteries (watt-hours) is given by the product of the battery voltage and the amp-hour rating. \$ E_{batt} = V \times Ah \$. The answer will be Wh (watt-hours).

The run time will be given by
\$ h = \frac {Wh}{W}\eta \$
where Wh is the battery capacity, W is your load and \$ \eta \$ is the inverter efficiency.

Note that battery losses increase at high discharge rates. The Ah rating is usually quoted for a 10-hour discharge rate. Discharge at a higher rate and the Ah capacity is reduced.

Comment: And if they are lead-acid batteries, then multiply the Ah capacity by 2. Because you shouldn't discharge them more than half-way for best life. In my experience, lead acid battery capacity is specified at the 20-hour discharge rate.

Comment: Good point. They will also deteriorate with age as well so doubling the capacity will help here too.

Answer (score 1):

You should put extra information in the question - not (only) in comments.

DOD% = percentage of full capacity allowed for discharge.
Assume DOD% = 60%

Battery Vmean x Ah needed = Power x 1/(DOD%) x hours
eg 24V supply, 60% allowed DOD, 2 kVA mean load, 10 hours.
VAh_battery = 2000W x 1/60% x 10h = 33,000 VAh.
At 24V mean = 1375 Ah.
Using 100 Ah Deep discharge batteries
= 14 x 24V 100 Ah
or 28 x 12V 100 Ah

Higher than Wouters figure due to 60% allowed DOD%.
Imean = 2000W / 24V = 83 A at 24A.
Per battery in 14P2S or 28P1S = 6A/battery.
= 100 Ah/6A = 16h rate (as you'd expect as 10h/60% ~= 17)
A few more batteries would be safer.
Say 30-40 x 100Ah 12V. (!)

ie about the same number as Wouter BUT 2 x capacity/battery.
Consider getting a standby alternator.
A 3 kVA gen set costs far less than that sort of battery capacity.

100 Ah deep discharge batteries are an industry standard.
If in USA buy Trojan Deep Discharge.
If elsewhere look carefully.

60% is too deep if you do 20 hour discharge often - even for DD cells.
80% say may be OK if you do full discharge only seldom.
Get them back to full charge ASASAP regardless.

Consider LiFePO4.
Higher capital cost.
Lower whole of life cost of ownership.
DO NOT discharge to 100% despite what some sellers say.